# [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: javascript, mysql

By this method, I got an error:

> The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object

I don't understand what is wrong here.

```
const customers = await Customer.findAll({
  where: { id: _.map(users, 'customerId') }
});

if (customers) {
  const status = req.query.activation
    ? await Customer.findAll({ where: { activation: req.query.activation } })
    : customers;
  const search = req.query.search
    ? await Customer.findAll({
        name: { where: { [Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } }
      })
    : status;

  return res.json({ search });
}
return response.sendBadRequest(res, 'customers empty!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id is string, i think for that we don't need to see your model

but _.map produces an array not a string

```
 map_.map(list, iteratee, [context]) Alias: collect
Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation function (iteratee). The iteratee is passed three arguments: the value, then the index (or key) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the entire list.

_.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
=> [3, 6, 9]
```

[Undeerscorejs Homepage](https://underscorejs.org/)

So what you can do is using join to get your string

```
const customers = await Customer.findAll({ where: {id: _.map(users, 'customerId' ).join('') }})
```

Comment: i add  `.join` but still getting the same issue

Comment: show me please your mpdel, i understand that users, 'customerId' gives you an arrays of numbers, what i don't understand is why customer id  is string at all it should also be integer